# Trying to scp to an EC2 instance, states sftp only?

Tags: wordpress, ssh, amazon-ec2, ftp

```
scp -Cpv -i /home/jamie/Downloads/jamie1.pem /srv/http/wordpress/wp-      content/themes/dt-the7 ec2-user@52.210.108.143:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/
```

[...]

```
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -p -t /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/
This service allows sftp connections only.
```

Can anyone tell me how to also allow ssh/scp connections?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify `sshd_config` on the server and restart the `sshd` daemon. The configuration will probably contain something like

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

if you will comment that out, you should be able to get `ssh` and `scp` access.

Comment: That's exactly what it was :) Just came to answer my own question but thanks anyway!